# ParcelJS - Functions available on windows object

Tags: typescript, parceljs, terser

I want to organise and expose my functions on the global `windows` object but whatever I try I cannot seem to achieve it.
My functions are written as `TypeScript` module, and this is how I would like to expose my functions:

> `window.namespace.utils.messageBox`
>   `window.namespace.main.initMain`

Here is my code:
index.ts

```js
import { Functions } from './src/Functions';

export default Functions;
// also tried window['namespace'] = Functions;
```

Functions.ts

```js
import { UtilFunctions } from './Utils/UtilFunctions';
import { MainFunctions } from './Main/InitMain/MainFunctions';

export module Functions {
    export var main = MainFunctions;
    export var utils = UtilFunctions;
}
```

UtilFunctions.ts

```js
import { MessageBox } from './MessageBox/MessageBox';

export module UtilFunctions {
    export var messageBox = MessageBox
};
```

MainFunctions.ts

```js
import { InitMain } from "./InitMain";

export module MainFunctions {
    export var initMain = InitMain;
}
```

After some searching and experimenting, I realised I needed to set a [Terser Miny Option](https://terser.org/docs/api-reference#minify-options):
.terserrc:

```js
{
  "mangle" false
}
```

And then I am building using the [--global flag](https://parceljs.org/cli.html#expose-modules-as-umd):
`parcel build index.ts --global namespace`

But when I inspect `namespace` in my F12 console:

```
namespace
{…}
__esModule: true
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

How can I put my functions onto the `namespace` object?

I am exporting everything - In fact it works okay if I do my dev build: `"dev": "parcel index.ts"`.
I think that production is putting everything in a Closure, is that right? That's the reason my functions are not exposed as I want them to be.

Answer (score 1):

So... It turned out that I had a `$ is not defined` when imppporting Bootstrap, so none of the code was being excecuted.
I have fixed the error and all works now..
The `--global namespace` and `export default` is giving me: `namespace.default.utils.messageBox`
So I prefer `window['namespace']` - It just removes the default...